# Range.replace method not replacing anything

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I've tried and tested this method with more simple formulas and it worked perfectly, however when I try it with my new longer formulas, it enters `FormulaPart1` into `range("J2")`, but doesn't replace the text with `FormulaPart2` and `FormulaPart3`.  The code also doesn't give any errors.

Basically, the formula calculates availability % which is

```
((Available Hours - Engineering Downtime)/ Available Hours) * 100
```

Please see my code below.

```
Sub ArrayFormCalc()

Dim FormulaPart1 As String
Dim FormulaPart2 As String
Dim FormulaPart3 As String
Dim S1 As Worksheet

Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(((INDEX(INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")),MATCH(RC6,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Shift""),0)" & _
               ",MATCH(R5C,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Date""),0))))-xxxxx,"""")"

FormulaPart2 = "SUMIFS(DT_Cur_Day_Hrs,DT_Equip,RC7,DT_Site,RC5,DT_Strt_Date,R5C,DT_Shift,RC6,DT_Cat,""Engineering Downtime"")" & _
               "+SUMIFS(DT_Nxt_Day_Hrs,DT_Equip,RC7,DT_Site,RC5,DT_End_Date,R5C,DT_Shift,RC6,DT_Cat,""Engineering Downtime""))/yyyy"

FormulaPart3 = "(INDEX(INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")),MATCH(RC6,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Shift""),0)," & _
               "MATCH(R5C,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Date""),0))*100)"

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

With S1.Range("J2")
    .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
    .Replace "xxxxx", FormulaPart2, xlPart
    .Replace "yyyy", FormulaPart3, xlPart
End With

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

End Sub
```

Comment: potentially your replace function is done on the value of cell J2 instead on the formula.

Comment: @SNicolaou - Potentially, but I'm not a 100% sure what you mean with "on the value of cell J2 instead of on the formula"?

Comment: i mean, do something like: 

   With S1.Range("J2")
    .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
    .FormulaArray.Replace "xxxxx", FormulaPart2, xlPart
    .FormulaArray.Replace "yyyy", FormulaPart3, xlPart
End With

Answer (score 1):

I can't identify the exact issue, but a possibility is that you are writing an invalid formula into the array before attempting to replace things. 
I suggest using the replace formula upfront on the string and only paste the final result into the FormulaArray.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function

Comment: When I use the replace formula upfront, it takes me back to my original error of "Unable to set the formulaArray property of the range class"

Comment: Okay, for me it's not clear if the error is in the syntax of this super-complex formula, or if writing into FormulaArray in general causes trouble for you. Perhaps try and write a much simpler Arrayformula first, like `=SUM(IF(R1C1:R5C1 = 4,1,0))`, also try and separate the formulas into 3 columns, then calculate them based on your first formula. You might find that the syntax error is in one of your 3 columns. Edit: looks like you would only need 2 columns (Available Hours and Downtime) ;-)

Comment: I think you're right.  I'll need to break this one down to basics to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application is set to use R1C1 references, you're trying to put R1C1 references into an existing A1 style formula which won't work. Either change the application to R1C1 style, add the formulas and then put it back, or change the two replacement parts to use A1 style references.

Comment: I've just tried both your suggestions, but it still won't replace.

Comment: Range.FormulaArray always works in R1C1, there is no dependency on program settings.

Comment: @Rob `Formulaarray` does, but once the formula is in the cell, `Replace` won't work to put an `R1C1` reference into a cell with a formula that is now in A1 style.

Comment: Ah good point, but I think the program fails on writing even the first part, as the formula contains invalid syntax, namely `-xxxxx`.

Comment: @1Charlie I suspect your formula is incorrect, since this doesn't work either: `.FormulaR1C1 = Replace(Replace(FormulaPart1, "xxxxx", FormulaPart2), "yyyy", FormulaPart3)`

Comment: @Rob - no that part does end up in the cell, it's the replacement that fails. As it happens, I think you are correct too that the formula string is invalid.

Comment: @Rory - I understand what you are saying.  The problem has to lie somewhere with the formula string and I need to break it up to find the solution.  The reason for the complexity is because availability needs to take into account if downtime occurred over the 24 hour mark going into the next day and allocate the to the current day and next day accordingly per machine.  I'll go back to the drawing board and see if I can find the solution.

Comment: @1Charlie do you have a working formula manually entered in the sheet? It's usually the best place to start.

Comment: @Rory - Yes I do and the formula works perfectly in there (so I was hesitant changing anything in there :) ) I will try for another hour so and if it doesn't work, then I will have to change my approach and split the results in the formula into separate areas in the workbook so that the final formula is a one liner instead of this complicated one.

Comment: @1Charlie In that case, select the cell with the formula, then in the Immediate window in the VB editor, enter: `?Replace(Activecell.formulaR1C1, chr(34), chr(34) & chr(34))` and press enter, then copy the result and add it to your original question.

Comment: @Rory - I went on the sheet and manually took it apart over several columns to make sure that the brackets don't cause issues.  I then took those separate parts to VB and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue was indeed in the syntax of the formula when splitting it up to be replaced.

The code below contains the correct split for the formula.

```
Sub ArrayFormCalc()

Dim FormulaPart1 As String
Dim FormulaPart2 As String
Dim FormulaPart3 As String
Dim S1 As Worksheet

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

Set S1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

FormulaPart1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")),MATCH(RC6,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Shift""),0),MATCH(R5C,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Date""),0))-xxxxx*100,"""")"

FormulaPart2 = "(SUMIFS(DT_Cur_Day_Hrs,DT_Equip,RC7,DT_Site,RC5,DT_Strt_Date,R5C,DT_Shift,RC6,DT_Cat,""Engineering Downtime"")" & _
               "+SUMIFS(DT_Nxt_Day_Hrs,DT_Equip,RC7,DT_Site,RC5,DT_End_Date,R5C,DT_Shift,RC6,DT_Cat,""Engineering Downtime""))/yyyy"

FormulaPart3 = "(INDEX(INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")),MATCH(RC6,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Shift""),0),MATCH(R5C,INDIRECT(RC5&""_""&TEXT(R5C,""mmm"")&""_Date""),0)))"

With S1.Range("J2")
    .FormulaArray = FormulaPart1
    .Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    .Replace "xxxxx", FormulaPart2, xlPart
    .Replace "yyyy", FormulaPart3, xlPart
    .Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
End With



End Sub
```